# Setting folder and files permissions

Tags: linux, centos, file-permissions

This is a 2 part question.

Recently my site was hacked, and I'm guessing the main way whoever it was who did it was some of my original sites might have had iffy permissions on the files/folders.

So, part 1. What are they best permissions for files and folders? From what I've read 644 for files and 755 for folders seem to be the best.

And part 2. In Linux is there any command I can do in the root directory to loop through all the folders and files in my sites and apply permissions to both files and folders? So I don't have to go through each directory manually applying permissions (I have ssh access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part2:

**Folders**

```
find -type d -exec chmod 755 \{\} \;
```

**Files**

```
find -type f -exec chmod 644 \{\} \;
```

Comment: Wow, much easier than I thought it would be! Cheers :)

Comment: You can write simply `{}` no need for backslashes

Comment: Part1. Allways think this about this: less permission = more security.

Comment: for Part2: I'd triple check that you can't put less permission than the ones above... for example, why "everyone" needs to read? can't it be just Apache (and its group, maybe) ?.  And also, some scripts underneath may need different permissions. And also, the '.htaccess' or other files of that kind should be further restricted!